# how to make "if" and comparison statement in uboot?

Tags: u-boot

i'm newbie in uboot and tftp programing

based on [this url](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/CommandLineParsing), there is how to make `if` statement like this `if imi $addr; then echo Image OK; else echo Image corrupted!!; fi`

and  this is my "if" :

```
=> setenv a true
=> printenv a
a=true
=> setenv b true
=> printenv b
b=true
=> if a b; then echo 'same';fi
Unknown command 'a' - try 'help'
=> if $a $b; then echo 'same';fi
Unknown command 'true' - try 'help'
=> if ${a} ${b}; then echo 'same';fi
Unknown command 'true' - try 'help'
=>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure if it is in all u-boot versions or not, but there should be a `test` command for comparison. Can you try:

```
if test "${a}" = "${b}"; then echo "same"; fi
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to u-boot, so this is all from memory.

Comment: yup it's correct... i've try this, if echo a b; then echo 'same'.. but before echo same, it also echo a & b variable... thanks...

Comment: [Here is the list of the various test operators](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/52ba373b7825e9feab8357065155cf43dfe2f4ff/cmd/test.c#L35).